# Beanshell preprocessor in jmeter to generate random number and use it in main script

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to create a random number and use it post request but getting errors, need help

HTTP request is like:

```
{
  "firstName": "Jmeter",
  "lastName": "LoadTest",
  "userName": "Jmeter${random}",
  "password": "pass8909",
  "primaryEmailAddress": "Jmeter${random}@gmail.com",
  "address": "",
  "city": "",
  "province": "",
  "postalCode": "",
  "country": ""
}
```

My Beanshell Preprocessor script is

```
vars.put("random",${__Random(1,1001)})
```

When i ran, it is not replacing ${random} with the value generated. Need help here

Answer (score 0):

1. [`vars.put()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#put(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) function takes 2 [Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) as parameters and you're trying to pass a non-String value to it. One of the solutions would be using [vars.putObject() instead](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object))
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), see [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) article for more details
3. You don't need any scripting there at all, just inline the [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function into your request body:

   ```
   {
     "firstName": "Jmeter",
     "lastName": "LoadTest",
     "userName": "Jmeter${__Random(1,1000,random)}",
     "password": "pass8909",
     "primaryEmailAddress": "Jmeter${random}@gmail.com",
     "address": "",
     "city": "",
     "province": "",
     "postalCode": "",
     "country": ""
   }
   ```